# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms... ' exception

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Calling `SomeFunction` from a referenced Dll in the console application

```
 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        SomeFunction();
     }
 }
```

throws the exception

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
> The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.Windows.Forms,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"} System.IO.FileNotFoundException

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2917268-3aa8-4311-a8e6-3fb59fc210f2/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-systemwindowsforms8230-visual-studio-2019?forum=winforms) and other answers, the problem could be a .Net version mismatch. The referenced dll that provides `SomeFunction` targets .NET Framework 4.8, while the Console Application targets .NET 5.0. (.NET 4.8 can't be selected here, only several versions of .NET core are available from the dropdown).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: you simply cannot.

Comment: I would say, the library is not fit for your usecase.

Comment: Does that mean you can never use a Dll referencing System.Windows.Forms in a Console Application?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense, yes. Maybe you can force it, but why would you. It's probably (very very very probably) going to shoot you in the foot any other turn.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? The dll uses an invisible Form to access OS-messages via WndProc. Why would it be unreasonable, to try using it in a .Net Console application?

Comment: ref winform from console can be reasonable. it is ref .net framework from .net core not.

Comment: This sounds like a solution: I just have to use a .NET Framework Console, instead of a .NET core.

Comment: you may need `[STAThread]` to decorate `Main` and finally you end up something similiar to a winform project structure.